# Hoe to change items size according to their position on the Scrollview : Android

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I'm creating a custom scrolview that need to contain a number of buttons

I want to set each button's size according to his position on the view (distance from the center) to create a "shrinking effect" when a button is scrolled out

this image can explain the effect

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KORJ.jpg)

I'm new with android development and I didn't find anything about this kind of scrolling gestures

how can such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using ViewPager instead of scrollView and create your custom PageTransformer class and set it

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new PageTransformer());
```

got to this link for reference [ViewPager animation](https://github.com/alibaba/UltraViewPager)

Comment: tnx helped me alot